# Override FlowPageBlockBtns CSS for Visual Flow page?

Tags: visual-workflow, css, button

Has anyone been successful in overriding the FlowPageBlockBtns CSS for a Visual Workflow VF page?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_customize_runtime_ui.htm

I want to center the buttons and have tried to override the Salesforce CSS several ways but none of them work, the buttons still end up with text-align:right.  See code and resulting screenshot where the override hasn't taken effect.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<style>
    .FlowPageBlockBtns, 
    .pbHeader .pbButton td,
    .pbHeader .td {
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        Quote Request Form
    </div>
</div>
<flow:interview name="Quote_Request_Form" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake -- I was running the flow directly instead of going to the VF page to let it run.  Arrggh!  The CSS overrides are working fine in the VF page.

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with CSS in Flows, but your image and *the documentation you linked to* indicates the buttons are a child of an element named `.pbBottomButtons` which holds each button inside it; apparently at the bottom. I suspect that's either a DIV or a TD depending on how the pageblock is constructed where the buttons are located.

If you actually do have a pageblock, you'll want to change your CSS to look more like this:

```
.PageBlock > .FlowPageBlockBtns {
   padding 5px 12px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

The `>` means that the one is a child of the other. Normally, I wouldn't consider a button or "button group" a child of a header unless it was contained within the header. They could easily be a child of a TD in this situation. The padding setting, may or may not be necessary.

**Note:** What I've written is based entirely on the documentation you referred to along with a bit of what you've included in your post and hasn't been tested. Use and adjust accordingly.

Comment: My mistake -- I was running the flow directly instead of going to the VF page to let it run.  Arrggh!  The CSS overrides are working fine in the VF page.